# A field isGroupable is FALSE but GROUP BY is still working

Tags: apex, soql, group-by

I have enabled the `Shield Platform Encryption` and encrypted the `BillingAddress` field of the `Account` sobject.

When checking the describe field result of the `BillingCountry` (sub-field of the `BillingAddress` field), it returns **false**.

I tried to use the `GROUP BY` clause for this field, and it was successful without any exceptions. It seems to conflict with the [Salesforce document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeFieldResult_isGroupable).

> **isGroupable()**
>
> Returns true if the field can be included in the GROUP BY clause of a
> SOQL query, false otherwise. This method is only available for Apex
> classes and triggers saved using API version 18.0 and higher.

Do you have any documents or issues related to this that I can explain to my customers?

Thank you,

Code sample:

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfr = Account.BillingCountry.getDescribe();
System.debug('isGroupable: ' + dfr.isGroupable()); // --> return false

List<AggregateResult> aggregateResults = [
SELECT BillingCountry,SUM(AnnualRevenue) 
FROM Account 
GROUP BY BillingCountry ]; // --> no exception
System.debug('group success');
System.debug('aggregateResults size: ' + aggregateResults.size()); // --> return size > 0
```

Comment: I have tried the same and got  Account.BillingCountry result as true which means it is groupable.

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala Did you encrypted the BillingAddress field?
In my org, this field isGroupable as false

Comment: Yeah BillingAddress is false even though it is not encrypted

Comment: > As per the document if you encrypt Billing Address encrypts Billing Street and Billing City and encrypted fields are not Groupable I read this document, but I don't know why they are `false` when checking the isGroupable by Apex code for `BillingCountry` and `BillingState`. And I am able to group them as well. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tw4O.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tw4O.png)

Comment: I suspect this unexpected behaviour relates to this being a compound field.

Comment: @PhilW can we log this bug for Salesforce?

Comment: @trong.nsy, Did you get chance to log case with salesforce so I can follow up on this

Comment: I see no reason not to raise a case. Be prepared to provide a minimum viable reproduction.

Comment: This is the case number (https://help.salesforce.com/s/case-view?caseId=500Hx000009IOQ5IAO). Please follow up on this, thanks @PhilW

Comment: @trong.nsy, Thanks for sharing it . I will follow up on this internally and get back to you. Can you share Case number instead of Caseid

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala The case number is 43707765. Thanks!

Comment: @trong.nsy, Thanks for confirming on it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for bringing up the issue and  waiting on the case. As per the investigation by our internal team this is logged as a bug (W-12208951).

```
Account.BillingCountry getting isGroupable as false though the same can be used in SOQL without any exception
```

A [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002zzVUQAY) is also been created for the same.